# Access Violation Reading Location using open file stream

Tags: c++, exception

I know that this question has been asked lots of times. But, in my case, the error is not always present so I think it might be different. I am using C++, Visual Studio 2013, Windows 7 x64.

Here's the relevant code:

```
void writeDATAToFile(const char *fname, string title, const VecDoub& spec_x, const VecDoub& spec_y, const VecDoub& freq)
{
    ofstream of;
    of.open(fname, ios_base::out);
    if (!of.is_open())
    {
        return;
    }
    of << "somename" << endl;
    of << "WAVES/S" << "\t" << title << endl;
    of << "BEGIN" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<spec_x.size(); i++)
    {
        of << spec_x[i] << "\t\t\t" << spec_y[i] << "\t\t\t" << freq[i]<<endl;
    }
    of << "END" << endl;
    of.close();
}
```

This function is supposed to write the spectrum data (calculated earlier in the program) and write it to a file. Some spectrum data won't cause a problem, some will. The error is in the for loop.
Here is the error window:[image]

Comment: And you are absolutely sure, that the other two vectors always have exactly the same size as `spec_x.size()`? (And there's only one `for` loop I can spot BTW)

Comment: When you say "The error is in the second for loop" I can only see one

Comment: Sorry, yes there is only for loop.

Comment: Yes, all vectors are of the same length.

Comment: @student1: Prove it, with an assertion.

Comment: Could the access violation come from the fname instead? ;-)

Comment: Just a note: Sometimes I will not get the problem when running on an XP x32 PC. How come?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing 3 vectors to your function:

```
const VecDoub& spec_x, const VecDoub& spec_y, const VecDoub& freq
```

but you never check that they have the same size.

In your loop (not the "second" loop as you said in your question, there's just one loop in the code you posted), you're iterating over `spec_x` and you use the same index `i` to index into the other two vectors.

What if one or both of your other two vectors have a smaller size than `spec_x`? Then you're indexing out of bounds which would cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: note: This is an access violation, rather than a V++ exception. I guess it might not show up in release mode e.g. with unchecked iterators....

Comment: All of them are of the same length, but I will double check.

Comment: @doctorlove I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: When I said V I meant C... typo. It's not a C++ exception you can catch

Comment: @student1: You can read about checked iterators on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx. Pay attention to: *If _SECURE_SCL is defined as 1, unsafe use of iterators causes a runtime error and the program is terminated. If defined as 0, checked iterators are disabled. By default, the value for _SECURE_SCL is 0 for release builds and 1 for debug builds.* So by default, iterators are checked for debug builds and unchecked for release builds.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly says it is trying to *read* something it shouldn't be.

You code loops thus:

```
 for (int i=0; i<spec_x.size(); i++)
 {
        of << spec_x[i] << "\t\t\t" << spec_y[i] << "\t\t\t" << freq[i]<<endl;
 }
```

This assumes `spec_x`, `spec_y` and `freq` are the same size.

- You could check this before looping and throw an error if this
  precondition doesn't hold.
- You could loop up to the smallest size of all three.
- You could leave this function as is and put checks where you populate the data originally.

Note - the debugger is trying to help you. If you hit "break" it will five you a call stack, and then you should be able to see exactly which variable is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check the length issue and get back.